# How to access the IR (Infrared receiver) with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, infrared

I need to access the raw data of the IR with cocoa, but not only the received from the Apple Remote. I saw this https://github.com/martinkahr/apple_remote_control but It's only for the Apple Remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from a quick browse over the source you linked to, it appears that what you're looking for is the I/O Kit.  Specifically the HID (human input device aspects of it).

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

This seems to be the bridging layer between Mac OS applications the the hardware itself.